# ActiveMQ in Katalon Studio

Tags: apache, automated-tests, activemq-classic, katalon-studio

Is it possible to somehow perform some actions in ActiveMQ using KS ? I know that with jMeter it is possible to work with ActiveMQ queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I search the documentation for Katalon Studio I can't find anything related to JMS so either the documentation doesn't cover it or it's not supported.

Comment: Yes, I searched about it too and didn't find anything related to JMS. So it doesn't have support to it. Thanks for your attention !